# wpf dynamic object explorer

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF and have searched for a while for following and came up with noting (not even a notion as to how to start writing it):

I need to build a GUI environment (WPF over C#) that will support instantiation of classes- meaning I want the ability to design new classes (not in the GUI), and have my GUI automatically (dynamically) expose their constructors (will let me build an instance of the class) and expose all of their properties for manipulation - an object explorer/ resource manager if you will..

the classes are to be decoupled from the GUI- I only need to GUI to be able to create instances of them on demand- maybe real life example would serve me better:
a programmer writes a new class:

> public class Person
>       {
>           #region Members
>           string _name;
>           #endregion
>
> ```
>     #region Properties
>     /// <summary>
>     /// The artist name.
>     /// </summary>
>     public string Name
>     {
>         get { return _name; }
>         set { _name = value; }
>     }      #endregion     }
> ```

I want the GUI to support creating instances of Person and viewing its properties (Name) without modifying the GUI code.
 I actually meant properties instead of fields I will correct it

Any tips, code examples or even a design idea on how to approach the problem would be much appreciated.

thanks,
mosh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try searching for Microsoft PRISM http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx
There are Microsoft's patterns and practices for creating a decoupled WPF style application. This is one example of a good way to create a WPF application.

Using C#, I would never expose fields as public - these should be at least wrapped in properties.

If you want to be able to set all properties on a class using a UI, I suggest you look at a property grid. WPF doesn't have one inbuilt (at least as far as I know - not without hacking WF in .NET 4.0) but you can download a free one from Codeplex by Xceed (http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) and there is even one available for .NET 3.5 if you dig through the available files. To use, decorate the properties you want to be manipulatable with the same attributes you would use for a Winforms property grid control - plenty of documentation available for you to search for.

I don't really understand your design objective - (possibly because as you are say -you are new to WPF) - Are you trying to design UI elements or classes using a custom UI? - Maybe people would be able to help if you provided a bit more specific and concise information?